# Why does a custom BaseRelation not get push-down filters (in buildScan)?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am implementing my own data source using the Data Source API.

I used several documentation I found on the web and came up with the following code:

```
public class MyRelation extends BaseRelation implements TableScan, PrunedScan, PrunedFilteredScan {
  public RDD<Row> buildScan(String[] requiredColumns, Filter[] filters) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(filters));
  }
}
```

I am getting empty filters using the following query:

```
SELECT field1,field2,field3 from table WHERE field2>4 AND field3=1000
```

which I ran:

```
SQLContext sqc = new SQLContext(sparkContext);
Dataset<Row> sqlResult = sqc.sql( query ).where("field2 > 4").filter("field2 > 15");
```

As you can see I also tried the API's `filter` and `where` functions but nothing worked.

I also tried the unhandledFilters function which was blank:

```
public Filter[] unhandledFilters(Filter[] filters)
{
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(filters));
    return filters;
}
```

I was expecting to get the filters "field2>15" and others in the `filters` array but it was blank.

Any ideas what I have done wrong and what can be done to fix the issue?

P.S. I did implement TableScan and PrunedScan and the correct method is called, when I run query which doesn't have the where clause and no filters still the function with filters (inherited from PrunedFilteredScan) is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone trying to accomplish the same task, I was able to solve the issue by implementing the `CatalystScan` Interface. Catalyst is the AQL query optimization mechanism and implementing this interface and writing the following function did the trick:

```
@Override
public RDD<Row> buildScan(Seq<Attribute> requiredColumns, Seq<Expression> filters) { ... }
```

Comment: I don't think you want to deal with `CatalystScan` as it's fairly low-level compared to the other interfaces/contract. Stick to `PrunedFilteredScan` as in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You should simply remove the other contracts from your `MyRelation`, i.e. `TableScan` and `PrunedScan`, as they get in the way and take precedence over `PrunedFilteredScan`.

Quoting [PrunedFilteredScan Contract — Relations with Column Pruning and Filter Pushdown](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-PrunedFilteredScan.html):

> `PrunedFilteredScan` is the contract of `BaseRelations` with support for column pruning (i.e. eliminating unneeded columns) and filter pushdown (i.e. filtering using selected predicates only).

This `filter pushdown` part is what you're after and is supported for `PrunedFilteredScan` relations in Spark SQL 2.3.

**TIP:** Have a look at [JDBCRelation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/jdbc/JDBCRelation.scala) as the only implementation of `PrunedFilteredScan` in the official distribution of Apache Spark 2.3.

Comment: Hi Jacek, In your example when my dataframe is built from a parquet file with FileScan ( `spark.read.option("basePath","/abc").parquet(Seq("abc/country=A", "abc/country=B"):_*))` ) and has partition filter (country in A and B), do `MyBaseRelation` will perform the partition pruning as well?

Comment: @Betta A nice question! You should ask a separate question on SO. In short, it won't since you've read what you wanted already.